# Wordpress Custom Post Type Archive Issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a blog with a custom post type inited like:

```
register_post_type( 'type',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Types' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Type' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
    )
);
```

Obviously this is wrapped in a function that is called by the init action. Problem is that this post type is full of posts, over 1K, but on the archive page (domain.com/type) there is nothing showing. I tried to verify the query, but the query is showing up as NULL. Anyone have a reliable solution?

PS - This is why I hate wordpress. Never works right.

Tags: wordpress-broken-again, wordpress-sucks, wordpress-i-hate-you

Full excerpt:

```
function cp_init_types() {
    register_post_type( 'nursing-home',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Nursing Homes' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Nursing Home' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'nursing-homes', 'with_front' => true ),
            /*'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search'=> false,
            'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag'),*/
        )
    );

    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
}

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if(is_category() || is_tag() || is_home() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        if($post_type) {
            $post_type = $post_type;
        }
        else {
            $post_type = array('post','nursing-home','nav_menu_item');
        }
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
        return $query;
    }

    return $query;
} 

// Show posts of 'post', 'page' and 'movie' post types on home page
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
add_action("init", "cp_init_types");
```

Comment: "I tried to verify the query, but the query is showing up as NULL. " can you add what you tried to your answer?

Comment: Phil, that is exactly my problem. Adding full code above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take note of this from the manual:

> In the same way single posts and their archives can be displayed using
>   the single.php and archive.php template files, respectively,
>
> single posts of a custom post type will use single-{post_type}.php and
>   their archives will use archive-{post_type}.php where {post_type} is
>   the $post_type argument of the register_post_type() function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Answer (score 0):

Your explicitly stating that you only want a soft-flush of the rewrite rules. To get custom post types to show you need need some rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file. Using a hard flush you can have WordPress add those for you. Remove the `false` parameter from the call.

```
flush_rewrite_rules(); // pass no parameters and it defaults to true
```